# Using Table with Python

Tags: python, prompt, tabular, hardcode

I need to incorporate a table into my python program so when I run my program it can read the information from the table as it is needed. What is the best way to incorporate the table into my program so that it is familiar with it when the program is ran?

This is the table that I will incorporate into my program:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use Excel or Google Sheets.

1. Paste the table into your spreadsheet
2. Export the sheet to CSV
3. Use Python's `csv` library to import the data

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html